# ThreeJS Maya like wireframe implementation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to implement a wireframe which displays quads instead of tris using this code

```
var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( _this.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } );
var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
_this.scene.add( wireframe );
```

This produces the following when the model is rendered

[image: Maya and Threejs wireframes]

As you can see from the image it is not displaying all of the edges, and is still displaying some tris. I need it to be similar to how Maya displays wireframes.

I have read that ThreeJS no longer supports Face4 which is why it always displays tris instead of quads, but i was wondering if there was a way around this? I have also seen some mention of using a pixel shader to display only the edges  of a mesh but i havnt been able to understand/get that working.

I would love some assistance on this one, either using existing threejs functionality, or by using a pixel shader somehow.

This is the model source (http://pastebin.com/21XUKYbw)

Cheers

Comment: `EdgesGeometry` does not render co-planar edges. The tris are likely not planar.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you for the response. I just read mrdoobs response on github issues. Does this mean there is no way to achieve what i want with threejs? It would be a shame to move to something else

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you want, and I have not experimented with your model, so I can't answer your question.

Comment: @WestLangley Sorry i thought my post covered it. I want to be able to display a wireframe with quad information instead of tris. I exported the model as quads so the information is there. My question is/was is it at all possible for me to do in threejs, and if not is it possible to do in a shader?

Comment: All I can suggest is you study `WireframeGeometry.js` and `EdgesGeometry.js` and figure out a hack to eliminate edges that are "diagonals".

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you for your comment :) I managed to figure this out eventually. It is a horrible hack but i hope i to make this an optional option. I have noticed there are a fair few people wanting this functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this for anyone who stumbles upon this issue in the future.

Following on from a comment made by WestLangley, i have modified the code within WireframeGeometry.js to ignore rendering the interior diagonals that are present when rendering a wireframe, which gives the appearance of quad faces. Which is more familiar to 3d artists.

[image]

This is the change I've made to the bottom of WireframeGeometry.js. This is admittedly a pretty hacky fix. The alternative would be to compute the lines you want to display before threejs performs triangulation. You could store the pre triangluated faces in a separate buffer.

```
        // non-indexed BufferGeometry
        position = geometry.attributes.position;

        var _i = 0;
        for ( i = 0, l = ( position.count / 3 ); i < l; i ++ ) {

            for ( j = 0; j < 3; j ++ )
                // three edges per triangle, an edge is represented as (index1, index2)
                // e.g. the first triangle has the following edges: (0,1),(1,2),(2,0)

                // Added a simple check here to only push the vertices that are not diagonal lines
                if(!(j == 2 && _i == 1) || !(j == 1 && _i == 0)){
                    index1 = 3 * i + j;
                    vertex.fromBufferAttribute(position, index1);
                    vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

                    index2 = 3 * i + ( ( j + 1 ) % 3 );
                    vertex.fromBufferAttribute(position, index2);
                    vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
                }
            }

            _i++;
            if(_i == 2){
                _i = 0
            }
        }
```